# IE Specefic css not called by internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make a website which behave differently on IE browser. I am doing this by calling a different css for IE browser and for another for different browser. But on IE browser IE SPECIFIC css is not being called

```
 <html>
    <!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" if="IE 8"/><![endif]-->

    <head>
        <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body id="bdy">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo">
    <div id="log_in">
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">

            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="left_div">
                   </div>
                <div id="right_div">
                    <div id="table_items"></div>
                    <div id="addv"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting `IE8 version` only then you have to use this conditional statement.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create seperate css file then following syntax.

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

For example you have class called borderright and you want to apply different style for ie8 then add your class like below.

```
.ie8 .borderright
{
  /*Your Style goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" if="IE 8"/><![endif]-->
```

is placed before `head` tag.

Put that code inside `head` tag !. And remove `if="IE 8"` part